# how to not specify an area for a form in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application where it has areas configured.  The logout link appears in the layout page so it is displayed on every page.  When I click the logout it always appends it with whereever the area it was in...

I just want it to go to Account\logout  - no area

I tried the following but it didn't work... any suggestions?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", area="" }))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a different overload. I think you should do that as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { area = ""}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```