# Logoff Form Submit results in 404 when using MVC Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following defined in the _Layout.cshtml for an MVC Area. Please note that I specify the area as being empty so that the action will be executed in the Account controller that is not in the Area but rather in the parent app. However, when the submit is executed the resulting URL is still defined as:

/REP/Account/Logoff

which results in a 404.  REP is the area within which this code is defined. I've looked online (google, stackoverflow e.g. [how to not specify an area for a form in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331423/how-to-not-specify-an-area-for-a-form-in-mvc-4) , etc) and everything I've seen seems to indicate that this code should function correctly and submit to the proper action:

/Account/Logoff

Any ideas?

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Logoff", "Account",
     new { area = "" },
     FormMethod.Post,
     new { id = "LogoutForm" }))
     {
          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('LogoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
     }
```

Comment: You're code doesn't even make sense. Please post what the form HTML looks like, I'm 99.99% sure it's completely incorrect (from an MVC point of view).

Comment: It looks formatted correctly, it' is html/razor.

Comment: I wouldn't know, you didn't post it.

Comment: Erik, your original post got me to look a bit closer at what was going on.  The Layout was contained within a parent parent layout (nested) which had its own login form.  I restructured the code a bit and all is well. Thanks for chiming it.

Comment: @xgp: Post that as answer and accept it when you can.